# Podfile error in during I have run pod install

Tags: ios, flutter

pod install
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Project at /Users/bobby/Downloads/mightytaxi-110/codecanyon-40977853-mightytaxi-flutter-online-taxi-booking-app-taxi-app-admin-backend-driver-app/Rider/Runner.xcodeproj does not exist. Please check paths or incorporate Crashlytics upload symbols manually.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.22.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "OneSignalXCFramework":
In Podfile:
OneSignalXCFramework (< 4.0, >= 3.4.3)

```
onesignal_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/onesignal_flutter/ios`) was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
  OneSignalXCFramework (= 5.1.3)
```

Specs satisfying the `OneSignalXCFramework (< 4.0, >= 3.4.3), OneSignalXCFramework (= 5.1.3)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I have this error. Please help to suggest.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your App deployment target? issue states **OneSignalXCFramework** framework requires higher deployment target and you have set it to something else. Deployment target mean minimum iOS version your app supports.

Answer (score 1):

OneSignal-XCFramework supports iOS 9 to iOS 14. You need to check your **Minimum Deployment Version**.
You can check it from,

**Your App target** -> **General Tab** -> **Minimum Deployments**

Update it to iOS 9 or above, this should solve your issue.

Here is an official GitHub link for your reference, [OneSignal-XCFramework](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-XCFramework)

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

if the prblm is not solved via @Pratik solution, then the prblm can be due to conflict in between cocopod version and package version. Recently when I updated my package dependencies, I was also facing this prblm, as newer package need higher cocopod version, I was also getting same error. To solve this first download the latest cocopod version by running this command:

```
pod repo update
```

After that you will see a link to download latest cocopod version.

After downloading latest version of cocopod, run below command:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Now you will see all the conflicting packages.

To update those package run command like this, you will see in console the command to update package:

```
run pod update Firebase/Analytics
```

Above command is demo command with Firebase Analytics package, you can see the command for conflicting package when you run the 2nd command `pod install --repo-update`

One more thing to notice if you have more then one conflicting package, you will see that when you resolve one package, conflict can arise for other package and if you try to resolve 2nd package conflict you will once again see conflict for 1st package, in that case note down the all conflicting package name from command and run command like below:

```
pod update Firebase/Analytics Sentry/HybridSDK
```

You can run the command in such way and write down all package name side by side with simple space in b/w, I was having prblm in these two package Sentry and Firebase Analytics, so I need to run pod update for all conflicting package together.