The pod "FirebaseAppCheck" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version
I am building an app with Flutter, using Firebase as backend. Until yesterday, building worked fine, but now suddenly it doesn't build anymore for iOS, instead giving me this error message:
Error: The pod "FirebaseAppCheck" required by the plugin "firebase_app_check"
requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than the plugin's reported
minimum version.
To build, remove the plugin "firebase_app_check", or contact the plugin's
developers for assistance.

Digging a bit deeper into the verbose output, I could also find this:
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAppCheck":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        FirebaseAppCheck (= 10.18.0, ~> 10.18.0-beta)

      In Podfile:
        firebase_app_check (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_app_check/ios`) was
        resolved to 0.2.1-16, which depends on
          FirebaseAppCheck (~> 10.22.0-beta)

    Specs satisfying the `FirebaseAppCheck (= 10.18.0, ~> 10.18.0-beta),
    FirebaseAppCheck (~> 10.22.0-beta)` dependency were found, but they required
    a higher minimum deployment target.

Does anyone have an idea what exactly this means and how to resolve it?
Because of the above main error message, I already tried increasing the iOS minimum deployment version but that wasn't the solution. It even gave me the error when I specified iOS 17.0
I also experimented a bit with the version requirement for the firebase_app_check plugin in my pubspec.yaml, both up- and downgrading it, but that didn't work either.

I set a minimum iOS deployment target to previous latest version in xcode and ran

pod install --repo-update

pod update Firebase/CoreOnly FirebaseAppCheck


1>which checks the dependent files
2>then updated the two packages identified in (1) together.

You need to update your cocopod version and after that need to update all packages in ios. Check out this answer of mine. It contains precise steps for it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78240465/22646405
